# Docker: Isolate compose stacks on network level, while allowing a single service to be reverse proxied by Traefik

Tags: networking, docker, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to secure containers on my homelab.

The main goal is:

- isolating **nginxA** and **nginxB**, so they are not able to talk to each other via `172.17.0.1` (eg. preventing **nginxA** from reaching **nginxB** via `172.17.0.1:5001`)
- isolating **nginxA** and **nginxB** from localhost, making them exclusively accessible via traefik
- Allowing **nginxA** to talk to **nginxA_DB**, which are in the same stack, but without allowing other containers nor traefik to talk to **nginxA_DB**

Each docker stack has a nginx/apache service with it's port exposed in docker-compose in the following manner:

**docker-compose-nginxA.yml:**

```
networks:
  internal:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.0/29

...SNIP...

nginxA:
  networks:
    internal:
      ipv4_address: 10.0.0.2
  ports:
    - "172.17.0.1:5000:80"
```

**docker-compose-nginxB.yml:**

```
networks:
  internal:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.0.8/29

...SNIP...

nginxB:
  networks:
    internal:
      ipv4_address: 10.0.0.10
  ports:
    - "172.17.0.1:5001:80"
```

Making these services only accessible via **localhost** (172.17.0.1) or **traefik**,

Traefik being also on the same machine with the following configuration:

```
http:

  routers:

    nginxA:
     entryPoints:
       - web
     service: nginxA

    nginxB:
     entryPoints:
       - web
     service: nginxB


...SNIP...

  services:

    nginxA:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://172.17.0.1:5000

    nginxB:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://172.17.0.1:5001
```

An idea was to connect all the containers in a same `/24` network with traefik, without exposing any ports via compose, but a single traefik network wouldn't isolate the containers from each other, only from the outside.

Another idea was to create a `/31` network for each container and merge all the networks traefik, but I'm unsure if this will do the isolation as intended. eg.

```
nginxA:
  networks:
    internal:
      ipv4_address: 10.0.0.2 # /29
    nginxA-traefik:
      ipv4_address: 10.50.0.1 # /31

traefik:
  networks:
    nginxA-traefik:
    nginxB-traefik:
  ...
```

Thanks for reading this far! Do you have any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. As in your last example, you want to create a separate network for each communication path you want between two containers. These can all be `/31`'s or `/29`s or whatever you want as long as the subnets are different.

Example:

- `nginxA-traefik` connecting `nginxA` and `traefik`
- `nginxB-traefik` connecting `nginxB` and `traefik`
- `nginxA-nginxA_DB` connecting `nginxA` and `nginxA_DB`

You should not do any port mapping on the `nginx` containers since `traefik` will communicate with them directly over the docker networks. This will allow each `nginx` container to communicate with `traefik` (and vice versa) but they can't communicate with each other.

---

However! This does not scale very well because you'll have to create/manage one network for every service connected to traefik which will quickly get unwieldy. A better way would be to create a single network for all traefik-linked services (e.g. `traefik_public`), connect all of your service containers (i.e. `nginx_A`, `nginx_B` and anything else) to this network, and add some rules to `iptables` to only allow traffic to/from `traefik`.

I wrote a pretty simple container firewall that will take care of the `iptables` rules for you automatically: https://github.com/kaysond/trafficjam
You just specify the network you want to protect (`traefik_public`) and the container to allow communication to/from (e.g. `ancestor=traefik:latest`) and it takes care of the rest!

Comment: You're a true champ, I think your method is way better than my solution (I ended up creating individual networks for 20 services). I'll check it out, and possibly reformat everything. Thank you!